# Can a dynamic 2D array implement the Java.Collection.size() method?

Tags: java, collections, int, type-conversion, long-integer

Okay, so I'm making a dynamic 2D array in Java that implements the java.util.Collection interface.  I made my array implement it because I wanted it to have the same functionality as a normal `Collection`.  However, I cannot implement the `size()` method because in the interface it returns an integer and a 2D matrix could potentially overflow an integer type.

Here's a snippet of my class I'm trying to make:

```
public abstract class AbstractMatrix<E> implements Collection<E>{
     @Override
     public long size() {
         return columns * rows;
     }
}
```

Now, this won't work because "The return type is incompatible with `Collection<E>.size()`", and if I change the type to int, columns * rows could overflow.

I know I can't override the size method like this, but is there any way I can make sure the method returns the correct size while still implementing the `Collection` interface?

Yes, I know this is impractical and will likely never be an issue, but I was interested to know if there was a good solution for it.

Comment: An overflow as in a matrix larger than 45k rows x 45k columns (assuming it is square)?

Comment: You plan for having more than 2,147,483,647 elements?

Comment: What could you *do* with a `size` that is `columns*rows`? What would it let you do with the matrix?

Comment: I think the question you should be asking is "do my use cases actually require size to be defined like this"? "Does my definition of size make sense in general"?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7632126/maximum-size-of-hashset-vector-linkedlist

Comment: Yes, I realize that this probably won't ever be used, but I was asking for the learning potential I guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although your implementation of `size` is questionable, the contract for `Collection#size` is defined in [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#size%28%29):

> Returns the number of elements in this collection. If this collection contains more than Integer.MAX_VALUE elements, returns Integer.MAX_VALUE.

So you could calculate the size as a `long`, and return `Integer.MAX_VALUE` if it is larger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Alternatively, you could mimic the way it is implemented in `LinkedList#add` for example, where `size` is simply incremented and is allowed to overflow.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you were willing to have an 8GB array -- the minimum size of a two-dimensional array that would overflow an `int` with its total size -- and assuming you were willing to do anything interesting with that collection, like iterate over it (costing several minutes at least just for the iteration)...

I believe the typical approach is either to back down to implementing `Iterable` and not `Collection`, or to just return `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, as specified by the Javadoc:

> Returns the number of elements in this collection. If this collection contains more than Integer.MAX_VALUE elements, returns Integer.MAX_VALUE.

Comment: Interestingly, LinkedList#add lets size overflow with no check.

Comment: It's not that surprising; your memory will usually run out long before you'll start hitting these kinds of issues.  (Also, it is difficult to imagine a use for `LinkedList`s that would scale up to that many elements in the first place.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are really concerned with large enough matrices that could overflow, you could ensure that does not happen by checking whether the resulting size (initialization or resize) would still be within the range of integer, and throw a (runtime) exception if that would be the case

Answer (score -1):

I don't think so, you will need to use a workaround of some sort.  You could maybe extend your size to return negative numbers and interpret them as unsigned 32 bit integers, which would give you a maximum of 4 billion and change.

Ask yourself though, do you really need to be able to support that many objects?  Keep in mind that 4 billion and change 32 bit integers will take up 16GB of RAM.  Using 64 bit java, a 4 billion long array of `Object` set to all null will take up 32GB because references on 64 bit java are 64 bits.  That doesn't even take into account the memory used to actually instantiate that many classes, which will in all likelihood be much higher.

Comment: Yes, I realize that it's impractical to have a 2D array that would overflow like this, but I was asking just to see if there is a solution.

Comment: Have you considered looking at the code for ArrayList. Why does your return type need to be long anyway?

Comment: mugafuga: ArrayLists are Collections, and have only `int size()`, no `long size()`.