# Bugs in Writing Division Algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, math, arraylist, linked-list

I've been writing a few methods to treat a LinkedList in Java as an infinite array for scientific notation. The first index is the integer, and the rest are decimals. I've been working on a division algorithm between two LinkedLists, but have had a lot of trouble. Right now, my code goes through an infinite loop. If somebody could please help me find the issue (I don't need a solution written for me xD), I would be nearly finished. Assume that other methods I wrote are correct.

```
public static LinkedList<Integer> divide(LinkedList<Integer> a, LinkedList<Integer> b) {
    LinkedList<Integer> arr = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    LinkedList<Integer> base = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    base.add(a.get(0));
    boolean incomplete = true;
    int i = 0;

    while (incomplete) {
        LinkedList<Integer> multiplier = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        multiplier.add(1);
        while (LinkedListMethods.lessThan(LinkedListMethods.multiply(b, multiplier), base)) {
            multiplier.set(0, multiplier.get(0) + 1);
        }
        multiplier.set(0, multiplier.get(0) - 1);

        LinkedList<Integer> multiple = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        multiple = LinkedListMethods.multiply(b, multiplier);
        base = LinkedListMethods.subtract(base, multiple);

        arr.add(multiplier.get(0));

        base = LinkedListMethods.clean(base);

        if (i == a.size() - 1 && base.get(0) == 0) {
            incomplete = false;
        } else if (i == arr.size() - 1) {
            a.add(0);
        }

        i++;
    }

    return clean(arr);
}
```

Thank you for any help!

Edit 1: lessThan(a, b) returns true if a < b (it's tested to work)

Edit 2: The other methods are up at http://javaman.net/code/larger-decimals (it's compact and unreadable for some reason)

Comment: (1) It's hard to help if you don't provide all the code (what is `lessThan`? etc.  See [mcve].(2) You should use a debugger and run your code step by step to understand the problem.

Comment: @QBrute The last `if` contains the `incomplete = false`, which probably never gets entered

Comment: @SomeJavaGuy Ah you're right. There it is. I'll delete my comment

Answer (score 1):

```
while (incomplete) {
        LinkedList<Integer> multiplier = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        multiplier.add(1);
        while (LinkedListMethods.lessThan(LinkedListMethods.multiply(b, multiplier), base)) {
            multiplier.set(0, multiplier.get(0) + 1);
        }
```

You never update the value of incomplete within the While loop, therefore it will always be true.  You need to update the value somehow or restructure your code.

[Maximum size of HashSet, Vector, LinkedList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7632126/maximum-size-of-hashset-vector-linkedlist)

Has some information on the upper pratical size of linked lists.  Even if in theory they have no upper limit, at some point you'll reach the limits of maximum value an Integer can have.

Comment: Each index (except possibly 0) is a one digit Integer, which means that the program is limited by available RAM.

Comment: @TheNewJavaman You're always limited by RAM if you're not explicitly dumping everything onto the disk, reading stuff only in parts.

Comment: @Zabuza that's true, I should've said that it's limited by RAM rather than the Integer limit in Java